# XPATH in Python - Performance difference between 2 different XPATH queries vs 1 Query with union operator?

Tags: python, xpath

I'm writing a basic crawler program in Python. To extract data I've tried to write individual components which extract a particular part of the page like this

```
def get_business_name():
  Executes('//h1/text()') # Gets the Business name

def get_business_address():
  Executes('//h2/text()')  # Gets the Business address

def get_business_contact_number():
   Executes('h3//text()')  # Gets the Business contact number
```

and then I call each function individually to get all the data about the business

Now, Even though the above method is  readable, is it efficient?
would I be better off calling all queries at once with the `Union |` Operator?

```
def get_all_business_data():
  Executes('//h1//text() | //h2//text() | //h3//text()')
```

This would be less readable

Therfore my question is,

1. Are there significant performance gains when using union operators over individual queries?
2. If yes, How may I make my code more readable/maintainable in doing so?

Comment: You can `timeit` to do the comparison.